# Merge a string in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$fields = $_GET['r'];
```

Which has some ids, for example:

```
Array (
[0] => 3134
[1] => 3135 )
```

and then I have this string in $tematiche:

```
3113,3120
```

How can I marge this string in the first array? Also, how can I remove the equals id (if any)?

Comment: `implode(",", $_GET["r"]);` see [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$fields = array_unique(array_merge($fields,explode(",",$tematiche)));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$fields = $_GET['r'];
$string = '3113,3120';

$array  = explode(",",$string);
$res_array  = array_unique(array_merge($fields,$array));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res_array);
```

Output :

```
Array (
[0] => 3134
[1] => 3135 
[2] => 3113
[3] => 3120
)
```

Comment: Edited the code now you will get all unique values `array_unique(array_merge($fields,$array));`

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `explode()`, `array_merge()` and `array_unique()` would be suitable.

```
// Make $tematiche into an array
$tematiche_array = explode(',', $tematiche);
// Merge the two arrays
$merged_array = array_merge($fields, $tematiche_array);
// Remove all duplicate values in the array
$unique_array = array_unique($merged_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this. This should work for you.

```
$a = explode(',', '3113,3120');
print_r(array_merge($fields,$a));
```